# How HBase uses ZooKeper?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, apache-zookeeper

I know that **ZooKeper** is platform for providing distributed synchronization.But how **HBase** uses **ZooKeper**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apache ZooKeeper is a client/server system for distributed
>   coordination that exposes an interface similar to a filesystem, where
>   each node (called a znode) may contain data and a set of children.
>   Each znode has a name and can be identified using a filesystem-like
>   path (for example, /root-znode/sub-znode/my-znode).
>
> In Apache HBase, ZooKeeper coordinates, communicates, and shares state
>   between the Masters and RegionServers. HBase has a design policy of
>   using ZooKeeper only for transient data (that is, for coordination and
>   state communication). Thus if the HBase’s ZooKeeper data is removed,
>   only the transient operations are affected — data can continue to be
>   written and read to/from HBase.

from [cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/10/what-are-hbase-znodes/)

## In a distribute System

In a distributed system *HBase splits table into Regional Server* and use two special tables , `-ROOT-` and `.META.`, to find where regions for various tables are hosted.

Like all tables in HBase, `-ROOT-` and `.META`. are also split into
regions. `-ROOT-` and `.META.` are both special tables; `-ROOT-` never splits into more than one region. `.META.` can split into as many regions as required (like other tables).

When a client application wants to access a particular row, it access the `-ROOT-` table and asks where to find the region responsible for a particular row. `-ROOT-` provides this information and redirect to  to the region of the `.META.` table .

Then:

**How do I find the `-ROOT-` table?**

The entry point for an HBase system is provided by another system called ZooKeeper.

## In a local sytem

In a local DataNode system you do not need ZooKeeper

## Conclusion

[ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org) is used by HBase in a distributet Regional system to look for  `-ROOT-` table.

see https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/hbase_who_needs_a_master

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apache ZooKeeper is a client/server system for distributed coordination that exposes an interface similar to a filesystem, where each node (called a znode) may contain data and a set of children. Each znode has a name and can be identified using a filesystem-like path (for example, /root-znode/sub-znode/my-znode).

In Apache HBase, ZooKeeper coordinates, communicates, and shares state between the Masters and RegionServers. HBase has a design policy of using ZooKeeper only for transient data (that is, for coordination and state communication). Thus if the HBase’s ZooKeeper data is removed, only the transient operations are affected – data can continue to be written and read to/from HBase.

Currently, hbase clients find the cluster to connect to by asking zookeeper. The only configuration a client needs is the zk quorum to connect to. Masters and hbase slave nodes (regionservers) all register themselves with zk. If their znode evaporates, the master or regionserver is consided lost and repair begins